# Can I extend Azure Monitor Alerts retention beyond 30 days?

Tags: azure, monitoring, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

We monitor several app insights instances from a dedicated subscription and have configured some custom alerts and all is working well.

Within Azure Monitor we can access the alerts and change state, add comments to each as necessary. This is ideal for our scenario.

The problem I have is that it appears to only retain 30 days worth of the alerts so is there any way I can configure this to be higher e.g. 90 or 365 days?

Comment: Microsoft is working on this.They have mentioned email id in feedback forum if you want to test this,Check this out - https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/17454031

Comment: Thanks but that just applies to the insights - the related Alerts only cover 30 days even if insights are retained 90 days.

Comment: Someone from Microsoft replied in another forum that they don't believe the log alerts can be retained beyond 30 days so I will take a different approach for that.